# MySQL: Insert on duplicate update problem with primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm running the following query... the issue I'm running into is that it saves the `id` field properly with rows 0-27 but then it tries to duplicate row 0.  Any thoughts on why this is trying to duplicate row 0?

```
INSERT INTO
        deal (`id`, `site_id`)
        VALUES (NULL, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = NULL,`site_id` = 1
```

Comment: What is the deal table? What is the purpose of the query?

Comment: is *site_id* UNIQUE? if not what is the point of `ON DUPLICATE KEY`? you get a new *id* with each INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> You can also explicitly assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

So, effectivly, entering `(0,'whatever')` is seen as `('the next autoincrement id','whatever')`. No duplicate key issues as far as MySQL is concerned. You can bypass this by using [`NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero). Note that using `0` as an identifier is not recommended practice.

Answer (score -2):

A PRIMARY KEY can't be NULL in MySQL, so your `UPDATE id = NULL` is casted to `UPDATE id = 0`.

See also: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/09/12/the-difference-between-a-unique-index-and-primary-key-in-mysql/